Mechanistic view of the universe
I was chatgpting and found Encouragement of the Mechanistic View The mechanistic view in physics is driven by several key principles:
Determinism: The idea that the future behavior of a system can be predicted with complete accuracy if its initial conditions and the laws of motion governing it are known.
Reductionism: The belief that complex phenomena can be understood by breaking them down into their simpler constituent parts and studying these parts individually.
Causality: The principle that every effect has a specific cause and that the laws of physics govern these cause-effect relationships.
Locality: The notion that interactions between objects occur at specific points in space and time, without instantaneous action at a distance.
My question is: What encourages a mechanistic view and how its related to reductionism and determinism ?
One blow to mechanical view was I think was action at a distance but does the concept of fields kept the concept of mechanistic view by introducing the concept of locality and answer to action at a distance ? Please explain to me the intricate relationship between causality and locality .
Anyone interested must read https://dn720201.ca.archive.org/0/items/evolutionofphysi033254mbp/evolutionofphysi033254mbp.pdf

I would say that it is pointless to discuss the relation between causality and locality, when the other two principles do not apply to reality.

@PerttiRuismäki explain

@andrós you missed the concept of fields

Following from Jo Wehler's answer I think the "mechanistic" should be replaced.  I'd use scientistic.  Some could find that a pejorative. Other possibilities: scientific physics oriented

Fields do not act instantaneously, so they are local. They are in fact causes.

@quanity Reality is neither deterministic nor reducible. Therefore it is not mechanistic regardless of how causality or locality turn out.

I'm under the impression that, at a high-level, 'mechanistic' is basically the same idea as 'deterministic'. In other words, the mechanistic view of the universe is that of a clockwork universe. If you know the initial conditions with absolute precision, you can predict all outcomes and why we can't do this is that we can't/don't know the initial states. There are many things about this idea that are challenged by contemporary physics but understanding the difference between chaos and randomness can help explain why this is not obviously wrong.

@JimmyJames I think "mechanistic" models attempt to answer "how" questions. You might come up with a model that requires fields, quantum entanglement, gravitons, etc, and it is still mechanistic as long as it handles "how".

You need to make clear what is produced by you & what is quoted from elsewhere. https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/editing-help

@SimonCrase To make sure I understand your comment, would you consider Newton's theory of universal gravitation to be answering 'how'? By that, I mean, it makes no attempt (t my knowledge) to explain why gravitation exists. In Newton's own time it was considered to be a kind of 'spooky action at a distance' in that its effect can be seen over vast distances between objects with no apparent connection to each other.

@JimmyJames Newton provided a simpler answer than Ptolemy to one how question: "how do all those shiny things in the sky move around?". He left the next question unanswered, but not without considerable thought: "how does this gravity stuff work then?".

Your mention of the link at the bottom of your question is far too casual. If you find yourself here, follow and save that PDF (while you can.)

An additional (perhaps minor) point: Maxwell himself spent his later years hypothesizing various mechanistic models for electromagnetic wave propagation in which space was filled with submicroscopic gear wheels and springs which transmitted movement by direct contact between machine elements, eliminating the need for fields as we conceptualize then today. This approach fell flat, for the following reasons:
To get the measured speed of light to come out correctly required that those little gear wheels and whatnot be almost massless and the springs and whatnot be almost infinitely stiff- ruling out any form of ordinary matter to make them out of.
Then you have the problem that ordinary matter can pass straight through that infinite array of space-filling gear wheels without any resistance. Hmm...
Finally you have the problem that to mechanically propagate waves in space through physical contact between gear wheels in three dimensions required those little gear wheels to mechanically engage one another in three dimensions in physically impossible ways.

Michaelson championed the Luminiferous Ether though, he really tried! The idea of a substance a million times stiffer than steel and a million times lighter than air (which matter could pass through with no resistance) filling the universe, didn't bother him.

@nielsnielsen does fields obey the mechanistic view ?

fields to not comport with Maxwellian mechanistics. modern physics has no use for mechanistics.

The term mechanistic is outdated. It characterizes Newtonian mechanics. Already in the 19th century Maxwell’s electrodynamics is a theory which cannot be understood in mechanical terms.

The principle of causality holds for the physical theories of
Newton, Maxwell, Boltzmann (thermodynamics and statistical
mechanics) and Einstein (Special and General Theory of Relativity).
The principle does not hold for quantum mechanics and quantum field
theories.

The principal of locality should be restricted to the first part of
the definition in the OP's post. Then it holds for all of the above theories
with the exception of quantum mechanics and quantum field theories: In general, the state of a quantum system has to be considered a field of probabilities (psi-function), and therefore the interaction via interference cannot be localized.

The principle of separability states that physical systems which are
separated in spacetime can be considered as separated systems. The principle holds for all of the above theories with exception of quantum theory: The
phenomenon of entanglement in quantum theory contradicts the
principle of separability.

Different from the principle of locality is the principle
“no instantaneous action at distance”: This principle is violated by
Newton’s mechanics and afterwards Boltzmann's thermodynamics and statistical mechanics. But it is satisfied by the other physical theories
above. An upper bound for the propagation of the causal effect is
the speed of light.

The question of reduction of theories is quite a different subject.
A textbook example is Boltzmann’s and Gibbs’ reduction of
thermodynamics to statistical mechanics. But the possibility of
general reduction is restricted. In general, distinct sciences work
with additional specific laws, which will not be reduced to the
deepest layer of elementary particles.


This short overview from the history of physics shows which of the above principles were successfully incorporated into which physical theories, while other principles had to be abandoned.

entanglement does not contradict locality.https://theoreticalminimum.com/courses/quantum-mechanics/2012/winter/lecture-7

why no causality in QM?

@quanity Thanks for your comment. I corrected and expanded my answer. I will listen to the lectures of Suesskind in the next time, thanks for the hint. - No causality: There are many examples where quantum theory principally does not provide a cause for specific single events.

Not sure if it is related, but individual elementary particles are 'identical' and cannot always be distinguished. Also a single photon or perhaps other particles cannot always be exactly localized, as in the two slit experiment. So, macro concepts don't fully apply to micro, or perhaps apply at all sometimes. An explanation only succeeds when it explains in entirely different terms from what is being explained, yes? And, reductionism doesn't work, as you say.

I think this answer would be improved by removing the first paragraph. Mechanics refers to treating physical systems as if they are machines, not Newton's use of a word which had been commonly used for that purpose for two thousand years before Newton (as Μηχανικά) and has remained in use for that purpose ever since, including among 21st century philosophers and physicists.

excellent answer. -NN

@quanity QM is extremely accurate in its predictions, but it lacks theoretical clarity because it confronts us with novel phenomena that clash with many of our traditional ideas, including causes, and the two dozen or so different interpretations of the physics at the micro-scale reduce to the same macro scales (i.e. it's hard to test which interpretation is correct). We've never had such an accurate theory with so many possible interpretations of it

@gs IMO the OP does not deal with "mechanics" in your sense but in a sense like in "Newton's mechanics". The OP does not speak about machines but about the principles underlying different theories from physics.

I don't think I've seen how statmech violates the speed of light/action at a distance, and I'm struggling to find search terms that bring it up. Can you explain/link me something?

@Kaia Statistical mechanics is based on Newtons's mechanics and takes over all its principles.

@JoWehler Ah, alright. Most statmech texts I've used present the fundamental assumptions of statmech independent of Newtonian mechanics and then use them to derive both classical gas statistics and Bose-Einstein/Fermi-Dirac, but it makes sense when we're talking about Boltzmann

The idea that 'mechanistic' applies to Newtonian mechanics only seems like a complete fabrication to me. I never once heard that during my (brief) time as a physics major.  And it should be obvious that quantum mechanics also uses the term 'mechanics'.

As you have probably understood from the book, the mechanical view of the universe is a thing of the past. Nowadays, how things works, is described (by physics) in terms of fields.
With regards to locality in a machine-like universe, you expect a specific part not to depend on, or affect another (except nearby); after all, that's what a machine is like: parts are not dependent on other parts, except if they are explicitly connected.
In regards to causality, although this concept can be "interpreted" in many ways, one thing is for sure: you expect a cause to precede the effect.
Both these concepts are challenged by the phenomenon of quantum entanglement, where a system is exchanging information with another, violating locality, while at the same time, makes cause and effect indistinguishable.
In fact the Nobel price 2022 was about this process.

@loannispaizis the locality principle applies to quantum mechanics. Let’s be as clear as
possible: It does.
Quantum mechanical entanglement is often referred to misleadingly as
nonlocality. But entanglement is not the same as nonlocality. Entanglement does
not mean you can send signals instantaneously from one place to another.
Locality is fundamental

@quanity Bell explicitly defined locality, and it is NOT "signals" but causation from outside a light speed boundary.  Entanglement explicitly violates locality.   Events outside a light boundary affect measurement within it.  Bell showed that "local realism" is not true of QM.

@quanity, Einstein was disproved officially in 2022, by the Nobel price

Does quantum mechanics violate locality? Some people think
so.
Einstein railed against the “spooky action at a dis-
tance” (spukhafte Fernwirkung) that he claimed was implied
by quantum mechanics. And John Bell became almost a cult
figure by proving that quantum mechanics is nonlocal.
On the other hand, most theoretical physicists, particu-
larly those who study quantum field theory, which is riddled
with entanglement, would claim the opposite: quantum mechanics done correctly ensures locality.
The problem, of course, is that the two groups mean different things by locality.

@IoannisPaizis go through Susskind quantum mechanics book chapter 6 and 7 or https://theoreticalminimum.com/courses/quantum-mechanics/2012/winter/lecture-7

The OP asked about mechanistic models, not mechanical. ... a mechanism explains phenomena by showing that they are produced by suitably organized components

@Simon Crase, download the book at the link of the OP. First think, then write comments.

@SimonCrase the author of the link is Einstein

@SimonCrase the link I provided is the book evolution of physics by Einstein

My comment was, "The OP asked about mechanistic models, not mechanical..." (The meanings of the two words are different: try a good dictionary). I don't believe that Einstein ever claimed to be an expert on English usage. Do you have any evidence to the contrary?

@Simon Crase, In th e OP's context, he is referring to mechanical, which is the term used in his proposed link-book.

@IoannisPaizis I repeat: the subject heading is "Mechanistic View of the Universe". Maybe his "link-book", as you like to call it, is indeed mechanical, but my comment relates to the question as he asked it.


What encourages a mechanistic view...

I've already argued in a comment that a mechanistic model attempts to answer a "how" question, e.g. how does the observed motion of the planets arise? Ptolemy attempted to answer this question, and Newton produced a simpler model. This led to the discovery of the planet Neptune.

Herschel discovered Uranus by good, old fashioned, observation.
Initially Newton's model didn't fit the data for Uranus terribly well, but John Adams and Urbain Le Verrier realized that the model could be made to fit if there were yet another planet out there. They independently calculated the position of their hypothetical planet, which was duly observed.

Getting back to your question: a mechanistic model may predict phenomena which may or may not be observed. Mechanistic models are encouraged by this possibility.
